# Class menu in Tkinter Gui

Tags: python, user-interface, class, menu, tkinter

I'm working on a Gui and I'd like to know if it is possible to make the menu property of a window a separate class on my script for a clearer and more enhancement prone code.

my code currently is :

```
class Application(Frame):
   """ main window application """
   def __init__(self, boss = None):
   (...)
   self.menu = Menu(self)
   self.master.config(menu = self.menu)

   self.select = Menu(self.menu)
   self.menu.add_cascade(label = 'Select', menu = self.select)
   self.select.add_command(label = 'Select all', command = self.select_all)
   ...
```

And I would prefer something like :

```
class MenuBar:

    # all the content of the menu here

class Application(Frame):
   (...)
   self.menu = MenuBar(self) ?
```

rgds,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
import tkinter as tk
# import Tkinter as tk  # if using python 2
import sys

class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        fileMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.add_cascade(label="File",underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=1, command=self.quit)

    def quit(self):
        sys.exit(0)

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        menubar = MenuBar(self)
        self.config(menu=menubar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello , no it doesn't work : I get the error message "AttributeError: MenuBar instance has no attribute 'master'" .

Comment: works fine, actually