# Menu, Button, etc. Bars in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to start a Tkinter application that follows [Class menu in Tkinter Gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520494/class-menu-in-tkinter-gui) for neatness but also add this functionality for e.g. Button bars, RadioButton bars, etc. Something like:

```
from Tkinter import *

def clickTest():
    print "Click!"

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        menuBar = MenuBar(self)
        buttonBar = ButtonBar(self)

        self.config(menu=menuBar)
        buttonBar.grid(row=0, column=0) ???

class MenuBar(Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Menu.__init__(self, parent)

        fileMenu = Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=clickTest)

class ButtonBar(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        firstButton = Button(parent, text="1st Button", command=clickTest)
        secondButton = Button(parent, text="2nd Button", command=clickTest)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

But I'm not sure how to get all of this to show up in the same window. Of course, the code as-is doesn't work. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did it with `pack()`. I am sure it can also be done with `grid()` but i am not much familiar with it.

```
from Tkinter import *

def clickTest():
    print "Click!"

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        menuBar = MenuBar(self)
        buttonBar = ButtonBar(self)

        self.config(menu=menuBar)
        buttonBar.pack()

class MenuBar(Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Menu.__init__(self, parent)

        fileMenu = Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=clickTest)

class ButtonBar(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        firstButton = Button(self, text="1st Button", command=clickTest).pack()
        secondButton = Button(self, text="2nd Button", command=clickTest).pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

---

Another thing is, you should set buttons parent as Frame like in this line:

```
firstButton = Button(self, text="1st Button", command=clickTest).pack()
```

Here i changed `parent` with `self`. `self` is the Frame itself, not the whole toplevel window. And with `pack()` function i packed the button in its parent which in this case the Frame.

Then with `buttonBar.pack()` i packed the buttonBar in toplevel window. You can also use grid here and in Frame.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Yeah, I just figured it out, too, with grid(). Thanks for the last suggestion for button's parent -- that fixed it for me.