# tkinter what constructor arguments to use for main class App(tk.Tk)?

Tags: python, tkinter

While trying to learn Python I can across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520494/class-menu-in-tkinter-gui)

Everything worked well until I moved the function from one class to the other.  I created a constructor in the child class and tried to call the newly placed function.  Obviously, this didnt work as I had hoped.  I narrowed the problems down to calling the constructor.  If I use app = App(self) that wont work because its looking for 1 argument, not 2 and if I leave out the arg it causes a recursion where both classes keep calling each other (I think).  Right now Im not sure what else to try

Any help you could provide is appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk


class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent)
        app = App(None)  # What needs to be called here?

        fileMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Copy", underline=1, command=app.copy_stuff)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=1, command=self.quit)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        menubar = MenuBar(self)
        self.config(menu=menubar)

    def copy_stuff(self):
        print("great")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent)
        app = parent

        fileMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Copy", underline=1, command=app.copy_stuff)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=1, command=self.quit)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        menubar = MenuBar(self)
        self.config(menu=menubar)

    def copy_stuff(self):
        print("great")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: that was it!  And after seeing it now, makes total sense but I just couldnt figure it out myself.  Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! Have fun app-developing!

Comment: This answer would be better if you described what you changed. Otherwise we have to go line-by-line and character-by-character to see what you changed.

Comment: The only thing I changed was the line in `class MenuBar`: `app = App(None)`, because you already call the app in the second-to-last line. `app = parent` enables you to access the app's `copy_stuff` method by defining the variable `app` that the "copy" command uses to access that method.